# Parse url string in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I'd like to parse a number from a url string in Excel and paste it in another cell using a formula. For example, I have https://system.google.com/childrecords.nl?id=668&t=CustomField&rectype=-704&weakdeps=T. I would like to use a formula to pull out '668' and place that in an adjacent cell. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want the first set of numbers and there is always an `=` sign and an `&` on either side then this will work:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("=",A1)+1,SEARCH("&",A1)-SEARCH("=",A1)-1)
```

Otherwise, here's a UDF that would work. You would paste this in a regular module in the Visual Basic Editor `Alt+F11` and use it like any other formula:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function FindFirstSetOfNumbers(MyRange As Range) As String

Dim NumCounter As Integer
Dim Start As Integer

Start = Application.Evaluate("=MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}," & MyRange.Address & "&""0123456789""))")

For NumCounter = Start To Len(MyRange)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(MyRange, NumCounter, 1)) Then
        FindFirstSetOfNumbers = FindFirstSetOfNumbers & Mid(MyRange, NumCounter, 1)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next NumCounter

End Function
```

Just type `=FindFirstSetOfNumbers(YourRange)` in any cell and press `enter`, or `=VALUE(FindFirstSetOfNumbers(YourRange))` to convert it to a number data type.

Answer (score 1):

i use the following formula:

```
=MID($A2,FIND(B$1&"=",$A2)+LEN(B$1)+1,FIND("&",$A2,FIND(B$1&"=",$A2)+LEN(B$1))-FIND(B$1&"=",$A2)-LEN(B$1)-1)
```

assuming the URL is on column A and the column title is the desired parameter.

```
$A2 = the URL string
B$1 = parameter name
```

the $ is on the correct place to allow copying the formula to several columns and all rows.

known cavities:

1. you'll have to prefix short parameter names with `&` if the name is a part of another parameter's name. for example in `?popup_id=1&up_id=2` a column title of `up_id` will be incorrectly `1` but `&up_id` will be `2` as intended.
2. any non-plain-english values would probably be encoded, but there's no native excel function to decode them. so `a%20value` will NOT be changed to `a value`.

usage example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DuUa8PWdf07PnZzFNouGF-byGs-3ygH44DvJbvdR00Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,SEARCH("id=",A1)+3,15),SEARCH("&",MID(A1,SEARCH("id=",A1)+3,15))-1)
```